# WPF Button Trigger Style Not recognizing background

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls, wpf-style

I am working on a button style and the hover effect is giving me some problems. I did a search but didn't find my answers (or didn't search correctly as is more likely) so I decided to ask here. I am specifying the following style in my WPF User control and then setting this style on a button.

```
<Style x:Key="TileButton" TargetType="Button">
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1" />
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Black" />
            <Setter Property="Height" Value="80" />
            <Setter Property="Width" Value="80" />
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="10,10,0,0" />
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FF91b220" />
            <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold" />
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FF91b220" />
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>

        </Style>
```

Everything seems to work except when I mouse over the button, rather than the background color staying consistent as I desire, it reverts back to the default WPF Light Blue color. I have tried adding other property changes, such as increasing the Height on mouse over, just to confirm that those changes take effect. It just seems to be the background that wants to block me.

TIA

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to completely override the inherited Windows style for buttons. Try adding the followinf snippet to your style.

```
<Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
            <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
            </Border>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
```

Also move your setters (or rather their content) for border on the border within the template.

Answer (score 1):

This behavior of a button is defined in the default button style, the 'mouse-over' color is defined as a binding. To preserve your color on mouse-over you can override the button template, smth like:

```
<Style  TargetType="Button">
                <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True"/>
                <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold" />
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />                   

                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                            <Border BorderThickness="1"
                                    Margin="10,10,0,0"                         
                                    BorderBrush="Black"                            
                                    Background="#FF91b220"
                                    Height="80"
                                    Width="80">

                            </Border>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>


            </Style>
```